# a connected geometrically unibranch algebraic stack of finite type over a field is irreducible

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, algebraic-stacks

Let $f:X\to \mathfrak{X}$ be a smooth presentation of geometrically unibranch connected algebraic stack by a scheme, which is geometrically unibranch since being geom. unibranch is local in smooth topology.

My question is: I know that geom. unibranch connected algebraic stack is irreducible, though I don't know how to prove this. I mainly follow the definitions in stacks project for those, but being geom. unibranch is a local property, while being connected or irreducible is the properties of the underlying topological space. So in this case, I argued in this way: let $\{X_\alpha\mid \alpha\in A\}$ be a set of connected components of $X$, then $f(X_\alpha)$ is both irreducible and open for all $\alpha\in A$. So $f(X_{\alpha}),\alpha\in A$ is an open cover of $\mathfrak{X}$, and if $f(X_{\alpha})\cap f(X_{\beta})\ne \emptyset$ for all $\alpha,\beta$, then $\mathfrak{X}$ is irreducible. But I don't know why $f(X_{\alpha})\cap f(X_{\beta})\ne \emptyset$ for all $\alpha,\beta$.

In addition, I guess that when restricted to any connected component, $f$ is still surjective, is that right?